# Laravel - building filter for results set using $_GET and query parameters in the url?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel project with a results set representing a number of articles. I am trying to filter the results set by author using an author dropdown on the right hand side.

I am trying to submit the form upon change of an author in the list, and have the author's name show up in the URL as one of the search params, e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/?author=Bob, but I am unsure of how to do this in Laravel.

I also have a second filter for types (below the first one), and it would be nice to have a chained url query when both of the filters are selected - for example:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/?author=Bob&type=review.

How can I send a GET parameter to the URL upon an on chance event and submit the form via a GET request?

My code so far: index.blade.php - showing author dropdown

```
    <div class="right-panel">
        <?php $_GET['author-checkbox'] = ""; ?>
        <form action="{{ route('articles.filter', $_GET['author-checkbox']) }}", method="get">
            @csrf
            <label for="author-checkbox" class="author selectbox">Filter titles by Author: &nbsp;</label>
            <select name="author-checkbox" onchange="this.form.submit()" id="author selectbox" class="author selectbox">
            
                @if(!empty($articles) && count($articles) > 0)
                    <option value="">--Please select an author--</option>   
                    @foreach($articles['data'] as $article)
                        @if(isset($article['authors'][0]))                        
                            @foreach($article['authors'] as $author)
                                <option value="{{ $author['id'] }}">{{ $author['name'] }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                @endif
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
```

// web.php - routes:

```
    Route::get('/articles/filter/?author={author}', ['as' => 'articles.filter', 'uses' => 'ArticleController@filter']);
```

// ArticleController.php

```
public function filter(){
if(isset($_GET('author-checkbox'))){ // filter titles by author
            $articlesJson = file_get_contents('https://content-store.explore.bfi.digital/api/articles');

            $typesJson = file_get_contents('https://content-store.explore.bfi.digital/api/types'); // Get list of available types.

            $objs = json_decode($articlesJson, true);

            $types = json_decode($typesJson, true);

            $filteredArticles = array();
            
            foreach($objs['data'] as $article){
                if(isset($article['authors'][0])){
                    if($article['authors'][0]['id'] == $_GET('author-checkbox')){
                        $filteredArticles[] = $article;
                    }
                }
            }

            $fullArticles = $objs;

            return view('articles.index')->with(['authorId' => $_GET('author-checkbox'), 'filteredArticles' => $filteredArticles, 'types' => $types, 'fullArticles' => $fullArticles]);

        } else if(isset($request->{'category-checkbox'})){

            $typeName = strtolower($request->{'category-checkbox'});
            
            $articlesJson = file_get_contents('https://content-store.explore.bfi.digital/api/articles?type=' . $typeName);

            $typesJson = file_get_contents('https://content-store.explore.bfi.digital/api/types'); // Get list of available types.

            $types = json_decode($typesJson, true);

            $objs = json_decode($articlesJson, true);

            $filteredArticles = array();
            foreach($objs['data'] as $article){
                if(isset($article['type']['name'])){
                    if($article['type']['name'] == $request->{'category-checkbox'}){
                        $filteredArticles[] = $article;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            $fullArticles = $objs;

            return view('articles.index')->with(['typeName' => $request->{'category-checkbox'}, 'authorId' => "", 'filteredArticles' => $filteredArticles, 'fullArticles' => $fullArticles, 'types' => $types]);
        }

If anyone has any idea, that would be great.
Thanks,
Rob
```

Comment: Please consider the excellent package https://github.com/spatie/laravel-query-builder!

Comment: Do you need to submit the form? Have you tried making an ajax request on author change and render the results in view file?